# Python panel Tabs titles on multiple pages or scroll button?

Tags: python, tabs, panel

I'm using Python panel Tabs to group some figures into different tabs, but when the number of tabs is large then tab headers don't wrap to second-third etc. lines or there's no left-right scroll buttons. I have to use horizontal scrollbar on the bottom of the page to scroll far to the right, click on a specific tab header and then scroll back to left.

Is there a way to see all tab headers in one page for example in multiple lines or with a small tab header scroll item on the left and right of tab headers ?

My code is below:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

from bokeh.plotting import figure

p1 = figure(width=300, height=300, name='Scatter')
p1.scatter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0])

tabs = pn.Tabs()

for i in range(50):
    tabs.append(('TAB ' + str(i), p1))

tabs.save(r'test.html')
```

The first image is what I see and the second image is what I expect:

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFDSb.jpg)

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppfkN.jpg)